# Why did reboot change to GNOME.?

Tags: gnome, reboot

Yesterday I spent a good few hours downloading and installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. With the Ubuntu desktop, side launcher bar with the Ubuntu logo button at the top to search the computer for apps and such. Today I've downloaded a few much needed programs.. and updated them. After one update I had to reboot. When the computer came back on the screen said GNOME instead of Ubuntu, and the desktop is completely different. The launcher is gone, the logo button is gone and all the carefully categorised apps, files and folders etc has all changed. Now I have a top bar with Activities in the top left corner and a few icons on the top right.

What happened.? I didn't change anything, click on anything or give any commands.

Comment: You can have several desktop environments installed on Linux machines without issues, It sounds like you have choosen 'Gnome' in the login dialog. So Please logout - which will most likely throw you back to the LightDM login-manager and there select your user. Then choose the session-type (most likely default/Unity/or something similar BUT NOT Gnome) and re-login. The session-selector might look similar to this: http://www.unixmen.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Selection_0031.jpg

Comment: There are no icons on the login page, nor anything to choose any options from. Just the Login link, that when clicked goes to the password field.

Answer (score 0):

When youre at the login screen there should be a little round icon above where you enter your password. If you click on it there should be a little menu. Find "unity" select it and then login.

Comment: Rebooted again, but there are no icons on the login screen. It's a black page with GNOME across the bottom, my name in the centre and Login underneath it. That's it.  When I click login, it asks for my password, and then brings me to the main Gnome desktop.

Comment: Sounds like you do see GDM not LightDM as login manager. Does it look similar to this? https://fedoramagazine.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/gdm-wayland.png

Comment: Yes.  But it says Login not Sign In, other than that, it's the same.

Comment: Well - it doesn't matter if its Sign in or login - its about choosing the session you want to run after login ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you saw [this screenshot by Dufte](https://fedoramagazine.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/gdm-wayland.png), right? Well, in that menu, select Unity, and click Login.